# SQL / SSRS 2008 - How to combine 2 conditions into a single condition in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement which appears simple enough but i cannot get this to work. I want to exclude a particular record in my resultset that meets TWO conditions, click the following image to see my current resultset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z93m3.png . I want to exclude any lines that have both a selling_price of £84.99 AND a vat_value of £40.83, in my case that would mean i want the last line of my resultset image excluded.

I've attempted to use the following as my SQL code:

```
SELECT     created_by, sales_order_number, sales_order_credit_line, qty_credited, sales_order_line, selling_price, vat_value

FROM         sales_order_credit

WHERE    (selling_price <> 84.99 AND vat_value <> 40.83)
```

However, as soon as i go to then run the query, the Query Designer reformats my code to read:

```
SELECT     created_by, sales_order_number, sales_order_credit_line, qty_credited, sales_order_line, selling_price, vat_value

FROM         sales_order_credit

WHERE     (selling_price <> 84.99) AND (vat_value <> 40.83)
```

Because my code now reads like that, it excludes all lines with a selling price of £84.99 and all lines with a vat_value of £40.83, which is not what i want - i only want to exclude lines that adhere to BOTH of those conditions.

I've ran into this before and never known how this should be done - any help is really appreciated.

Jacob

***EDIT - Responses to Comments***

**VKP** -  thanks for your suggestion, when i add your code it changes to:

```
SELECT     created_by, sales_order_number, sales_order_credit_line, qty_credited, sales_order_line, selling_price, vat_value
FROM         sales_order_credit
WHERE     (NOT (selling_price = 84.99)) 
          OR
          (NOT (vat_value = 40.83))
```

Again, it takes the two and puts them into completely seperate conditions seperated by OR - which is not what im looking for

**Ubiquitous Developers** - there is a difference, if you do the reformatted version of the code it will exclude line 4 AND 2, whereas i only want line 4 excluded as it meets both conditions, whereas line 2 only met 1 of the conditions (selling_price)

Comment: use `not (selling_price = 84.99 AND vat_value = 40.83)` which is equivalent to saying `(selling_price <> 84.99 OR vat_value <> 40.83)`

Comment: There is not difference between (selling_price <> 84.99 AND vat_value <> 40.83) and (selling_price <> 84.99) AND (vat_value <> 40.83)

Comment: try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: I've edited my post to respond to VKP and Ubiquitous Developers

Comment: You should read about de Morgan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: http://rextester.com/FILX72808

Comment: Am i missing something very simple here? Surely there is a simpler answer than 30+ pages of history on Boolean algebra and theories?

Comment: `(selling_price <> 84.99 AND vat_value <> 40.83)` is exactly the same as `(selling_price <> 84.99) AND (vat_value <> 40.83)`, which is why the query designer reformats the code. Either expression will match all rows that have both a `selling_price` different from `84.99` and `vat_value` different from `40.83`. They will not match rows that match one of the conditions but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right thing to do in your case is the next:

```
SELECT     created_by, sales_order_number, sales_order_credit_line,  qty_credited, sales_order_line, selling_price, vat_value
FROM         sales_order_credit
WHERE     NOT (selling_price = 84.99 AND vat_value = 40.83)
```

Comment: I had tried this and replied to this suggestion in my question, it reformats the code to read as two seperate conditions

Comment: But the two conditions (NOT (selling_price = 84.99 AND vat_value = 40.83)) and ((NOT (selling_price = 84.99)) OR (NOT (vat_value = 40.83))) are equivalent.

Comment: If your issue is that the visual query editor changes the condition when you press "Ok", why don't you correct the condition from ((NOT (selling_price = 84.99)) OR (NOT (vat_value = 40.83))) to (NOT (selling_price = 84.99 AND vat_value = 40.83)) in the Management Studio main window? This seems to be a limitation on the graphic query builder.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE  (selling_price <> 84.99) OR (vat_value <> 40.83)

Try it yourself: [rextester](http://%09%20rextester.com/FILX72808)